# How to enable shortcodes for WordPress category titles?

Tags: wordpress

I want to enable shortcodes for category headers on my website.
A category page is an archive page displaying items related to the category. On the headers of other pages types shortcodes are processed without problems.

I need the shortcodes to display the current year and month in the header.

I tried adding this code to functions.php of my theme, but it didn't work:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'add_shortcode_to_title' );
function add_shortcode_to_title( $title ){
  return do_shortcode($title);
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's not "working" is because [the_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_title/) filter hook only works with post/page/custom-post-type titles.

For archive titles, including category page titles, you want to use the [get_the_archive_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_the_archive_title/) filter hook instead, like so for example (untested but it should work, if not please leave a comment):

```
function wp5542_theme_archive_title( $title ) {
    return do_shortcode( $title );
}
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', 'wp5542_theme_archive_title' );
```

(This all assumes that your theme renders category titles using standard WordPress functions.)

[image: Code in functions.php]

[image: Using the shortcode on the Category Edit page]

[image: Category Archive page showing the modified category title]

Comment: Unfortunately it's not worked :(

Comment: It might be an issue with your WordPress theme then @Support. I just tested this code with the Twenty Twenty-One theme and it worked as expected, see https://imgur.com/a/8gdwDzf

Comment: I use bricks builder and custom theme, it can cause a issue? my website is https://atlantwallet.io

Comment: You'll want to reach out to the developers of Bricks Builder and of your custom theme and see what suggestions they may have about this.